# Circle CI fails for robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, circleci

Hi I trying to figure out why circle CI fails to get my robot framework running.
I use the command.
`robot -d results -v inputEmail:circleci@xx.co  tests/flow/investor_flow.robot`
to run the code on my local machine. 
I have added the whole repo to git hub and added a circle.yml file which looks like this.

```
test:
  override:
    - robot -d results -v inputEmail:circleci@aurorax.co  tests/flow/investor_flow.robot
general:
  artifacts:
    - "robot_results"
```

Here is the requirement.txt file

```
robotframework
robotframework-selenium2library
robotframework-requests
```

And lastly the picture of the structure for my folders.

[image]

Here is the error generated by circle ci

```
robot -d results -v inputEmail:circleci@aurorax.co  tests/flow/investor_flow.robot
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'tests/flow/investor_flow.robot' failed: Data source does not exist.

Try --help for usage information.

robot -d results -v inputEmail:circleci@aurorax.co  tests/flow/investor_flow.robot returned exit code 252
```

Which is odd since in my local machine the same code works.

Comment: Could you link to your github repo? I would hazard to guess it is a problem with relative paths.

Comment: @MrName My repo is private.... I can provide as much as information here as possible

Comment: Gotcha, I was just wanting to confirm that `tests/flow/investor_flow.robot` is definitely checked in to the repo.

Comment: @MrName I just checked, yes it is there, but its written on capital letters.
 Just like in the pictures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the path to capital letters.
`Tests/Flow/investor_flow.robot`

Comment: More specifically, CircleCI is building your project on a Unix-like machine so capitalization in the filesystem is important.